# Bitcoin API for getting an input script?

Tags: api, database, input-script

I wanted to try talking to my bitcoin node to get the input scripts and put them into a database. Does anyone have good resources on where I can look to get started?

Comment: So what I want to get access to is tap scripts. Like the one in mempool where they have:

OP_PUSHBYTES_32 526cfd93ec81e49633486ba01d9c8c3954e6fd755836539b9441f66a32f3beb5
OP_CHECKSIG
OP_0
OP_IF
OP_PUSHBYTES_3 6f7264
OP_PUSHBYTES_1 01
OP_PUSHBYTES_9 696d6167652f706e67
OP_0
OP_PUSHDATA2 89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4948...(there's more I left out for the sake of space)
OP_ENDIF

Is there a way to get this from the RPC API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getrawtransaction.html and note the comment about `-txindex`

The description of the verbose result shows the unlocking script (scriptsig) for each input.

There's a different RPC call noted for wallet transactions .